# ASSERT condition for driving vehicles in Veins failed

Tags: omnet++

I generated plenty of routes (~90.000+) using SUMO's `ACTIVITYGEN/DUAROUTER` with a configuration [file](http://pastebin.com/KM2cqYRZ) and different durations (`--duration-d 1`, `--duration-d 7`, ...).

The resulting `.rou.xml` is successfully executed by SUMO without serious errors. Just some warnings about invalid `departPos`.

But when using Veins, I receive the following error message:

> ```
> <!> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd)
> Scenario.manager (id=6) at event #2327172, t=25619.2: Model error:
> ASSERT: condition count == drivingVehicleCount false in function
> processVehicleSubscription,
> veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc line 640.
> ```

I removed the ASSERT condition and displayed both values. `count` is always higher than `drivingVehicleCount`.

The included "veins" example is running without any problems.

I am using:

- SUMO 0.22.0
- OMNeT++ 4.6
- Veins 4 alpha 2.

In addition, I tested Veins 3.0 and receive the same error message.

Did somebody encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting out the `ASSERT` is totally fine.

In SUMO any vehicle can have one of five states (according to `statesvehicleStates_sm.uxf`): first, it is *loaded*, transitions to *running* when it starts driving, then transitions to *arrived* when it arrived at its destination. In addition, *running* vehicles can temporarily become *teleporting* or *parking*.

Veins subscribes to these state changes to keep track of the number of driving vehicles. To make sure that the bookkeeping is correct, it compares its own count against SUMO's reported number of active vehicles.

I do not know why the numbers do not match sometimes. It only seems to occur in large congested networks.